# Microsoft graph NotificationUrl scheme='http' is not supported

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

While trying to create subscriptions (using the `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions` endpoint) from local system with notificationUrl schema "http", it throws following error:

```json
"code": "InvalidRequest", "message": "NotificationUrl scheme='http' is not supported."
```

Is not "http" should be allowed for development purpose?
Also, can I give "localhost" in subscription's "NotificationUrl" ?

Answer (score 1):

Only https is supported for `notificationUrl`.
As described in the [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/subscription):

> The URL of the endpoint that will receive the notifications. This URL
>   has to make use of the HTTPS protocol.

Localhost doesn't work.
You will receive a response like this:

```
{Code: InvalidRequest Message: Invalid notification url='localhost'.}
```

If it wouldn't be rejected by the server you would be unable to receive any notifications (as localhost would be interpreted as the microsoft graph server-ip).

Answer (score 0):

For development purposes, you can use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com) to tunnel to your http localhost. Check out the [readme](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnet-webhooks-rest-sample) for instructions on using ngrok this way.